# Как заблокировать вызовы JS из Console?

Tags: javascript, консоль

Насмотревшись на Facebok, решил блокировать вызов JS функций из консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент я вывожу заглушку об использовании консоли и переопределил:

```
 console = new Object();
```

Тем самым заблокировал использования любых log-ов.

**Вопрос состоит в следующем:**
*Можно ли как то отслеживать ввод команд в консоль, либо заблокировать совсем?*

Comment: Даже если вдруг окажется можно, ваш js-код просто подредактируют так, чтобы убрать все отслеживания и блокировки

Comment: ...иначе говоря, тех, кто сознательно полезет в консоль, это всё равно не остановит.

Comment: интересно, а как связана команда `console` и вызов js в консоли браузера?

Comment: в чем смысл блокировки именно `console.log` ?

Comment: Не вижу на фейсбуке ничего про серые списки...

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что вы уже в них) Но вообще это не фейсбучная надпись, а уже собственно ТС

Comment: Я не могу быть уверен но если функции обернуты в анонимную функцию то их сложнее вызвать(я пока и не смотрел можно ли их вызвать как-либо вообще). Тем не менее я уверен что опытные разработчики/хакеры найдут способ обойти это и отредактировать сам скрипт. Я просто оборачиваю все функции в общую анонимную что бы неопытные пользователи случайно не запустили что-то не то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ранее это было возможно только в обозревателях сети, основанных на Chrome. Но сейчас разработчики Chrome эту возможность отключили.

[Об этом сообщил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693931/) инженер по безопасности в Facebook (на английском). В своём ответе он вкратце описал как он это делал.

Также один из пользователей сообщил там о том [как это было ранее сделано на Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21795086/) (на английском). Подробное описание.

Тем не менее существует возможность просто напугать пользователя, выводя [цветные записи в console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console).  К примеру так:

```
console.log('%cОстановитесь!\nВыполнив действия в console ваша учётная запись окажется в чёрном списке!', 'color:#f00;font:bold 26px "Courier New";background-color:#000;padding:16px;padding:50px 500px');
```